# Laravel Query Build with nested Right Joins

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have a query that works but I need to get it into the Query Builder:

```
RIGHT JOIN (tlkpSUDesc RIGHT JOIN tblSU ON tlkpSUDesc.SUDescCode = tblSU.SUDescCode) ON tlkpSUTyp.SUTypCode = tblSU.SUTypCode
```

I can figure out how to do it.  I tired this:

```
->rightJoin('tlkpSUDesc', function($join) {
$join->on('tblSU', 'tlkpSUDesc.SUDescCode', '=', 'tblSU.SUDescCode');
}
'tlkpSUTyp.SUTypCode', '=', 'tblSU.SUTypCode')
```

But that didn't work.  I also tried

```
->rightJoin('tlkpSUDesc', 'tlkpSUTyp.SUTypCode', '=', 'tblSU.SUTypCode')
->rightJoin('tblSU', 'tlkpSUDesc.SUDescCode', '=', 'tblSU.SUDescCode')
```

But that didn't work either.

Thanks!

Comment: I never saw that type of nested joins... I recommend you 100% to use relationships and drop those weird and complex queries... what you can do (if `->rightJoin` does not work), is use a `raw` query (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-expressions, see if any of the next stuff in that documentation helps)

Comment: @matiaslauriti I am not sure what you mean by "I recommend you 100% to use relationships ".  Sorry I am new to this and trying to navigate through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @matiaslauriti that there's nothing wrong with reaching for raw expressions. But, since you asked and it can be done with the query builder, try this:

```
$query = \DB::query();

$query->rightJoin('tlkpSUDesc', function ($query) {
  $query->rightJoin('tblSu', 'tlkpSUDesc.SUDescCode', '=', 'tblSU.SUDescCode')->on(
    'tlkpSUTyp.SUTypCode', '=', 'tblSU.SUTypCode');
})->toSql();
```

Comment: I did get this to work (the whole query):

```
$sql = "SELECT tblSU.Site, tlkpSUDesc.ESR_SUcat, tlkpSUDesc.ESR_SUcatdisp, tlkpSUDesc.SUDesc, tlkpSUTyp.SUTyp, tblSU.SUNum
FROM tlkpSUTyp
RIGHT JOIN (tlkpSUDesc RIGHT JOIN tblSU ON tlkpSUDesc.SUDescCode = tblSU.SUDescCode) ON tlkpSUTyp.SUTypCode = tblSU.SUTypCode
WHERE (((tblSU.Site) = '$id') AND ((tlkpSUDesc.ESR_SUcat) = '$category') AND (Not (tblSU.SUTypCode) = 'GEN'))
ORDER BY tblSU.Site, tlkpSUDesc.ESR_SUcatdisp, tblSU.SUDescCode";

$selectStructures = DB::select($sql);
'''
Any issues doing it this way?

Comment: I'd say just use the query directly using PDO:
 
$statement = \DB::getPdo()->prepare($sql);
$statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$statement->execute(['id' => $id, 'category' => $category]);
$result = collect($statement->fetchAll());

Bind id and category by replacing the variables with :id and :category. Gather up the results in a collection as that's all you'd be missing. Sometimes it's better to unshackle yourself from the query builder.

Comment: Gist: https://gist.github.com/shawnlindstrom/46ec3710d50fbacffbd7699b26cd1dee

Comment: @ShawnLindstron Your other comment was really help and i rebuilt my queries using get Pdo.  Thanks!!